# Marking / flagging files in a way that is visible to a windows batch file

Tags: backup, batch-file, metadata

I would like to construct an automated procedure for transferring files from my Windows desktop to a remote storage for backup. I envisage the automation being done by a Windows batch file.

To minimise costs of remote storage, I would like to be selective in what gets backed up. For example, I have several hundred gigabytes of photographs, many of which are near-duplicates or of generally low quality. It would suffice to back-up the best 10% or so of these files. Similar points go for other types of file.

Ideally, I would like to do this without having to break my existing local file organisation structure. So my question is:

> Is there a robust way (in Windows 10) to mark or flag files such that a batch file can be told to perform a given operation only on those files that are flagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to point out the Windows Backup and Restore(Windows 7) basically does all of this for you, as well as compress the backup a bit and IS on the Win 10 install I am currently looking at.

I don't have time to write out a full answer for you right now but I may be able to get you started.  The following link is about [looping a batch file through a directory](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html).  The `Archive bit` was built for what you are looking for.  So you can combine the `For /d` with `attrib *?wildcard.fil` to either remove or set the archive bit.

**Attrib syntax** `attrib .\filename.xxx` will output the file's current attributes

`attrib -a c:\pathtofile`

This can also be seen if you right-click and select properties for a file.  Near the bottom you will see `Read-Only` and `Hidden` and `Advanced` to the right of those.  In advanced there is a checkbox that says "Ready for archiving" meaning the archive bit is on.

Your batch might look something like this

`For /d attrib A *.jpg
copy %G x:\destination drive\folder
attrib -a %G
end for`

I'm not sure on the syntax for the %G which is an attempt at 'current file' or ending the For loop.  Will add to this if I get more time later.

Comment: to add to this, you should only have to set the archive attribute for what you want the first time, then it should set itself when a file is modified